# Reversing string C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, loops, char

I tried to create a code that reverse a string, I think my loops logic is correct. But I don't know what is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"How many letters does your string have >> ";
    int nbre;
    std::cin>> nbre;
    int a;
    a=nbre-1;            
    char normal[a]={};
    char reverse[a]={};
    std::cout<<"Enter your string >> ";
    std::cin >> normal;
    for (int i=0;i<=a;i++){
        normal[i]=reverse[a-i];
    }

    std::cout << "The reversed string is >> " << std::endl;
    for (int u=0; u<=a; u++){
        std::cout<<reverse[u];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0Ubk.png)

Comment: I assume you are not permitted to use `std::string` and you are stuck with character arrays and VLAs that are illegal in standard `c++`.

Comment: There are loads of things you can do better to improve your code but if you just want it working; you wrote `normal[i] = reverse[a-i]` in reverse. Instead it should be `reverse[a-i]=normal[i]`

Comment: @lucieon it works perfectly thank you. What can I do to improve my code ?

Comment: BTW, `char normal[a]` is a VLA and not standard C++; your compiler may have an extension for it.  For dynamic arrays, either use `new` or use `std::vector`.

Comment: You will need to use `std::getline(cin,...)` to limit the number of letters input.  Otherwise, your character array may be overwritten beyond its capacity.

Comment: Before printing a character array, verify that the last character is a `'\0'`, or terminating nul character.  Otherwise the `std::cout` will print characters until it finds one (could access memory beyond your program).

Comment: [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use constant to declare an array this way:

```
char normal[a]={};
char reverse[a]={};
```

You can allocate memory like this instead:

```
char* normal = (char*)calloc(a+1, sizeof(char));
char* reverse = (char*)calloc(a+1, sizeof(char));
```

and free it once done using it.

The `+1` is because you have to account for the ending null char.
I don't think letting the user account for it is a good idea unless your users will only be C-programmers... Better change `a = nbre-1;` to `a=nbre;`.

Finally, you should have meant to write your for-loop as:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
    reverse[i-1] = normal[a - i];
}
```

I made many changes to your for loop. I will let you do the Homework to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would load the input string into a char array and iterate backwards, starting at the end of the input array and just doing some index math.

Let n = input string length

Iterate from i = n-1 to 0, and load input[i] into reversed[n-i]. Luceion is correct; you're not doing the correct method of actually reversing input string in the first for loop.

Comment: Just use [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) and you are done. One line of code. Why make it complicated?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'm not sure if this person is allowed to use the reverse function, as their uploaded code made it seem to me like they were asked to rewrite the function.